# Twiiter4j StatusListener method wont show Tweets

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

want to see online tweet streaming,  I have Authorized my credentials first then Implemented StatusListener Method further I implemented onStatus method which given me status variable to display status, I have also Introduced TwitterStream but I cant see the tweets, I was once able to see tweets yesterday when I added a break point but now it wont goto break point anymore, my code is as below

```
package com.example.mapo;

import twitter4j.FilterQuery;
import twitter4j.StallWarning;
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.StatusDeletionNotice;
import twitter4j.StatusListener;
import twitter4j.TwitterStream;
import twitter4j.TwitterStreamFactory;
import twitter4j.User;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

public class SimpleStream {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true);
        cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("**************");
        cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("*****************************");
        cb.setOAuthAccessToken("***************************");
        cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("*******************");

        TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();

        StatusListener listener = new StatusListener() {


            @Override
            public void onException(Exception e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatus(Status status) {

                User user = status.getUser();

                // gets Username
                String username = status.getUser().getScreenName();
                System.out.println(username);
                String profileLocation = user.getLocation();
                System.out.println(profileLocation);
                long tweetId = status.getId();
                System.out.println(tweetId);
                String content = status.getText();
                System.out.println(content +"\n");

            }

            @Override
            public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice statusDeletionNotice) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int i) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onScrubGeo(long l, long l1) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStallWarning(StallWarning stallWarning) {

            }
        };
        FilterQuery fq = new FilterQuery();

        String keywords[] = {"ireland"};

        fq.track(keywords);

        twitterStream.addListener(listener);
        twitterStream.filter(fq);

        System.out.println(twitterStream.sample());
        twitterStream.cleanUp();
        twitterStream.shutdown();

    }
}
```